# Splitting a tweet into separate strings

Tags: c, xcode, twitter, xcode4

I'm new to the site. Does anyone know if it is possible to take a tweet and split the information in it into separate sections in Xcode? For example ...
If the tweet read...
"Sky News:This is the headline:on 12/04/12:This is the body of the message"
can I extract the chunks separated by the colons as separate strings so that one string could be "Sky News" one "This is the headline ...etc?
Thanks in advance
Al

Comment: Not sure how this is specific to tweets...

Comment: Thanks Tom & sch,
I need to split the tweet so that I can display it as for example
Title,
Date,
Body,
and control where they sit on a display detail page. For instance, I may want to have 'Title' in bold and the body in a different font. I'll need to search for tweets with a specific hashtag - say '#breakingnews', then separate it as above. 

With the method that you have suggested above [@"This: is: a: string"] I suppose this relies on a specific text, obviously when I am pulling in tweets, I cannot control what the ("This: is: a: string") detail will say. What would you suggest here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` you can split the string into an array of strings.

```
NSArray *arr = [@"This: is: a: string" componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

Now the array `arr` will have 4 items.

Comment: Thanks Tom & sch, I need to split the tweet so that I can display it as for example Title, Date, Body, and control where they sit on a display detail page. For instance, I may want to have 'Title' in bold and the body in a different font. I'll need to search for tweets with a specific hashtag - say '#breakingnews', then separate it as above. With the method that you have suggested above [@"This: is: a: string"] I suppose this relies on a specific text, obviously when I am pulling in tweets, I cannot control what the ("This: is: a: string") detail will say. What would you suggest here? Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is a language processing library... And that's something which even the biggest companies out there are sometimes still struggling to get right.